# SQL Server - How to get Max of Sum referencing a field that is not in the aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

DB: SQL Server 2017

How to get the product along with it's biggest client and the sum of units sold?

The data:

```
Client_Name, Product_Category, Units_Sold    
Client1,Product1,10
Client1,Product2,20
Client1,Product2,33
Client1,Product3,30
Client1,Product3,6
Client2,Product1,5
Client2,Product1,22
Client2,Product2,15
Client2,Product3,35
```

Result:

```
Product1,Client2,27
Product2,Client1,53
Product3,Client1,36
```

Maybe with some OLAP Function?

Thanks

BR

Comment: there exists `Product1,Client1`?

Comment: Looks like basic aggregation and then ROW_NUMBER to get the "first" in each group.

Comment: Not sure why somebody thought this question was "too broad". It could have used some help with sample data but it is pretty clear what they want.

Comment: @SeanLange it's my go-to for all "I haven't done any research, somebody do my work for me" questions.  Unless I can quickly find a duplicate of course.   It's broad because it's not focused to which technique he doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. I broke this into step with ctes so you can see the logic. This could be simplified a little bit but the performance is not likely to be any different.

Notice how I posted a table and sample data that is easy to use? This is something you should do in the future.

```
declare @Something table
(   
    Client_Name varchar(10)
    , Product_Category varchar(10)
    , Units_Sold int
)

insert @Something values
('Client1', 'Product1',10)
, ('Client1', 'Product2',20)
, ('Client1', 'Product2',33)
, ('Client1', 'Product3',30)
, ('Client1', 'Product3',6 )
, ('Client2', 'Product1',5 )
, ('Client2', 'Product1',22)
, ('Client2', 'Product2',15)
, ('Client2', 'Product3',35);

with Totals as
(
    select Client_Name
        , Product_Category
        , UnitsSold = SUM(Units_Sold)
    from @Something
    group by Client_Name
        , Product_Category
)
, RowCounts as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Product_Category order by UnitsSold desc)
    from Totals
)

select rc.Client_Name
    , rc.Product_Category
    , rc.UnitsSold
from RowCounts rc
where rc.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--Try This, Works good with me.
select d.Product_Category,d.Client_Name, sum(d.Units_Sold) as Sum_Units_Sold
into #temp1
from data d
group by  d.Client_Name,d.Product_Category
order by d.Product_Category,sum(d.Units_Sold) desc
Go
with temp2 as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Category ORDER BY 
Product_Category ,Sum_Units_Sold desc) AS GeneratedRank,
Product_Category,Client_Name,Sum_Units_Sold
FROM #temp1  
)
select Product_Category,Client_Name,Sum_Units_Sold from temp2 where 
GeneratedRank = 1
```